# одни и те же данные в разных адресах памяти

Tags: ассемблер

подскажите почему в разных адресах одни и те же данные. а в исходнике asm файла они идут друг за другом как и в екзешнике, только с нового параграфа
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сначала DS ссылался не на правильные данные, после двух операций, на правильный адрес, по которому находятся те же данные что и в CS на третьем параграфе.
Или же только таким образом будет возможность различать команды и данные если они будут иметь разные адреса? В общем суть вопроса, как туда попали эти данные?

Comment: Это на самом деле одна и та же память. физический адрес в реальном режиме вычисляется путем умножения сегментного регистра на 16 (сдвига влево на 4 бита) и прибавления сегмента смещения. 0xB6E+(32/2)=0xB70 https://studfiles.net/preview/2665973/page:8/

Comment: понятно, спасибо. по подсчётам всё совпадает, и надо видимо понимать что это физ адрес который выделили именно только для данного экземпляра программы?

Comment: Да, в при следующем запуске эта область памяти может оказаться занята и выделят другую. DOS вообще выделяет первый попавшийся (от начала цепочки свободных) подходящий по размеру блок. Но учитывая, что DOS не многозадачаен обычно вы будете видеть одни и те же адреса

Comment: @Mike, оформите ответом?